# Why can't I fight Omega Mark XII?

Tags: final-fantasy-12

I just traveled through Giruvegan to fight Omega Mark XII (he's one of the last optional bosses I have left to beat) and he's just sitting there. Why won't the fight begin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha, I checked GameFAQs and [found this answer](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps2/459841-final-fantasy-xii/faqs/42270):

- By accepting Yiazmat's hunt you can now fight Omega Mark XII in Great
  Crystal.